# FocusNode should lose focus when clicking outside the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

does anyone know how to make a focus node loose focus when clicking outside the focus node ? Basically, I got something like this:

```
      InkWell(
        focusNode: focusNode,
        child: ...,
        onTap: () {
          ...
        },
      ),
```

But the focusNode doesn't lose his focus when I'm clicking outside the InkWell widget.

I have tried to use the FocusTrap widget, which seems to do exactly that. But I can't get a focusScopeNode from my focusNode, all I get is null (I don't really understand how focusScopeNode works)

Note that I can't do something hacky like

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Focus.of(context).unfocus();
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    // ...
  ),
);
```

Because I'm in a package context

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: `Focus.of(context).unfocus();` isn't hacky. What do you mean by "package context"?

Comment: Wrapping your entire app inside a GestureDetector to call unfocus on tap seems kind of hacky to me. But I can't do that because that code is for a package, not an app. So I can't wrap an entire app inside a GestureDetector to call unfocus on tap